# How to fetch only desired property of bean in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, criteria, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I am using Hibernate 3.5.6 for my application.In this application I am using hbm.xml files to map my POJO to database table columns.

In this application I have User bean as below.

```
public class User {
// login info
private long id;
private String type; 

private String userName; 
private String password; 
private String securityQuestionStr; 
private String securityAnswer; 

// personal info
private String firstName; 
private String middleName;
private String lastName; 

/**
 * <b>{@link GenderType} gender</b>
 */
private GenderType gender;

private Date dateOfBirth; 

// other related info
/**
 * <b>{@link UserType} userType</b>
 */
private UserType userType; 

// contact info
private Long mobileNo; 
private Long businessPhoneNo; 
private Long homePhoneNo; 
private Long faxNo; 
private String email; 
private String alternateEmail;

/**
 * <b>{@link RegistrationStatus} userStatus</b>
 */
private RegistrationStatus userStatus;

/**
 * <b>{@link Post} posts</b>
 */
private String securityAnswerHash;
private String passwordHash;
private String encryptedPassword;
private String encryptedSecurityAnswer;
private String nationality; 

private String portal;
private float version;
private Date createdDate;
private User createdUser;
private String createdIP;
private Date lastModifiedDate;
private User lastModifiedUser;
private String lastModifiedIP;
private boolean recordStatus; 
private String publicKey;
private String certificateName;
private String signPublicKey;
private String signCertificateName;
private boolean isEtoken;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getSecurityQuestionStr() {
    return securityQuestionStr;
}
public void setSecurityQuestionStr(String securityQuestionStr) {
    this.securityQuestionStr = securityQuestionStr;
}
public String getSecurityAnswer() {
    return securityAnswer;
}
public void setSecurityAnswer(String securityAnswer) {
    this.securityAnswer = securityAnswer;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getMiddleName() {
    return middleName;
}
public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
    this.middleName = middleName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public GenderType getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(GenderType gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}
public Date getDateOfBirth() {
    return dateOfBirth;
}
public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}
public UserType getUserType() {
    return userType;
}
public void setUserType(UserType userType) {
    this.userType = userType;
}
public Long getMobileNo() {
    return mobileNo;
}
public void setMobileNo(Long mobileNo) {
    this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
}
public Long getBusinessPhoneNo() {
    return businessPhoneNo;
}
public void setBusinessPhoneNo(Long businessPhoneNo) {
    this.businessPhoneNo = businessPhoneNo;
}
public Long getHomePhoneNo() {
    return homePhoneNo;
}
public void setHomePhoneNo(Long homePhoneNo) {
    this.homePhoneNo = homePhoneNo;
}
public Long getFaxNo() {
    return faxNo;
}
public void setFaxNo(Long faxNo) {
    this.faxNo = faxNo;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getAlternateEmail() {
    return alternateEmail;
}
public void setAlternateEmail(String alternateEmail) {
    this.alternateEmail = alternateEmail;
}
public RegistrationStatus getUserStatus() {
    return userStatus;
}
public void setUserStatus(RegistrationStatus userStatus) {
    this.userStatus = userStatus;
}
public String getSecurityAnswerHash() {
    return securityAnswerHash;
}
public void setSecurityAnswerHash(String securityAnswerHash) {
    this.securityAnswerHash = securityAnswerHash;
}
public String getPasswordHash() {
    return passwordHash;
}
public void setPasswordHash(String passwordHash) {
    this.passwordHash = passwordHash;
}
public String getEncryptedPassword() {
    return encryptedPassword;
}
public void setEncryptedPassword(String encryptedPassword) {
    this.encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword;
}
public String getEncryptedSecurityAnswer() {
    return encryptedSecurityAnswer;
}
public void setEncryptedSecurityAnswer(String encryptedSecurityAnswer) {
    this.encryptedSecurityAnswer = encryptedSecurityAnswer;
}
public String getNationality() {
    return nationality;
}
public void setNationality(String nationality) {
    this.nationality = nationality;
}
public String getPortal() {
    return portal;
}
public void setPortal(String portal) {
    this.portal = portal;
}
public float getVersion() {
    return version;
}
public void setVersion(float version) {
    this.version = version;
}
public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}
public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}
public User getCreatedUser() {
    return createdUser;
}
public void setCreatedUser(User createdUser) {
    this.createdUser = createdUser;
}
public String getCreatedIP() {
    return createdIP;
}
public void setCreatedIP(String createdIP) {
    this.createdIP = createdIP;
}
public Date getLastModifiedDate() {
    return lastModifiedDate;
}
public void setLastModifiedDate(Date lastModifiedDate) {
    this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
}
public User getLastModifiedUser() {
    return lastModifiedUser;
}
public void setLastModifiedUser(User lastModifiedUser) {
    this.lastModifiedUser = lastModifiedUser;
}
public String getLastModifiedIP() {
    return lastModifiedIP;
}
public void setLastModifiedIP(String lastModifiedIP) {
    this.lastModifiedIP = lastModifiedIP;
}
public boolean isRecordStatus() {
    return recordStatus;
}
public void setRecordStatus(boolean recordStatus) {
    this.recordStatus = recordStatus;
}
public String getPublicKey() {
    return publicKey;
}
public void setPublicKey(String publicKey) {
    this.publicKey = publicKey;
}
public String getCertificateName() {
    return certificateName;
}
public void setCertificateName(String certificateName) {
    this.certificateName = certificateName;
}
public String getSignPublicKey() {
    return signPublicKey;
}
public void setSignPublicKey(String signPublicKey) {
    this.signPublicKey = signPublicKey;
}
public String getSignCertificateName() {
    return signCertificateName;
}
public void setSignCertificateName(String signCertificateName) {
    this.signCertificateName = signCertificateName;
}
public boolean isEtoken() {
    return isEtoken;
}
public void setEtoken(boolean isEtoken) {
    this.isEtoken = isEtoken;
}
```

}

Now when I want to fetch User from databse, I have used *criteria or get or load* method.
But when I saw the query which is generated by hibernate, the query length is too high.This is because I have 38 property in User bean.As all property are of type of String and primitives (no any of property is type of Has-A another bean class)

But my actual required id only for 10-12 or may be only 20 properties at a time.I don't want  hibernate to fetch every property on fetch User bean.

For this I have seen HQL In which I can give only number of property in constructor which I want to fetch only.
Like below:

```
Query query = session
            .createQuery("select new User(id, userName) from User where id=?");
    query.setParameter(0, 1l);
```

It will fire query only to fetch id and UserName so the query length is short and also I got properties which I required only.

But it is very difficult to write query every time with different type of properties required and it also need to required same signature constructor in POJO class.
It will be more difficult when some collections and other beans in User class and also want to fetch at the same time.

So I want to know is there any other ways to restrict hibernate to fire query only for required properties (string or primitive types) not for all.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like premature optimization to me, especially if your query only returns one User instance as in your instance.

Not only that, but it's actually very confusing, because the query doesn't return a complete User: it returns a User with nearly all the fields set to null, which might break the invariants of the class, and there is no way for the caller to know if some field is really null in database or if it's null only because your query chose not to load it.

I would first measure if loading these fields really cause a performance problem, and only optimize if and where there is one. And I would use a dedicated UserDTO which would only contain the fields actually loaded by the query. You might also look at [fetch groups](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching-lazyproperties), which enable lazy-loading of properties, but as the reference manual says:

> Please note that this is mostly a marketing feature; optimizing row
>   reads is much more important than optimization of column reads.
>   However, only loading some properties of a class could be useful in
>   extreme cases. For example, when legacy tables have hundreds of
>   columns and the data model cannot be improved.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an Utility that will prepare such dynamic query for you.

```
DataBaseUtil.createPropertySpecificQuery(Clazz entity, String[] properties, String[] conditionParams, String[] conditionOperators){} write a logic to build query.
```

When you have associated collection in your POJO you can add logic that make use of joins.

I found it useful and would prefer this over DTO as they reduce lot of headache of managing them for conversion, change etc.